# Virtual Path Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

I am currently trying to create multiple Applications within a single IIS-Website automatically.
Each application represents a Feature-Branch of a developer/feature.

The problem is, that the legacy application is not really made for running in a path that is not on the root. So the path the application thinks (and must think) it is running in, must be '/'. 
It would come with re-structuring and re-testing pretty much everything related to urls, to change this. So for now, its not an option.

What i currently have:

```
[Features (Site)]
  - [Feature_A (App)]
  - [Feature_B (App)]
```

This results in Feature A being available under http://server/Feature_A and Feature B respectively.

Now when the Request reaches the application, the application must think that the url in which it was called is "http://server/" (or the Path being "/").

Chosing the correct app was achieved with the IIS URL-Rewrite module, and works quite well.
I use a cookie to decide which app to call, and the original '/' is rewritten to '/Feature_A/'

But now, when trying to eliminate the "/Feature_A" part of the Path within the app seems to be quite impossible.

```
Application.Context.RewritePath(newPath); // throws exeption -> different application
```

didnt really work out, because the new Path '/' points to a different application, and RewritePath doesnt like that.

Is there any way within the app or even in IIS to make the app think it is running on the root path?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to host an ASP.NET site somewhere other than the root (/) then you need to be careful when developing it to always use paths that are either relative or virtual root relative (~/). Why do you want to host them all under a single IIS site anyways? What's wrong with creating new sites? You want to be very careful when hosting them under the same site because of configuration inheritance.

Comment: For some company policy reason we cannot register a widcard dns entry, so we only have one dns entry / endpoint pointing to this site. 
The root site basically just does the url-rewriting. there is no other configuration here, so we wont get into trouble when putting several apps below it.

Comment: So why not host them on the same domain name, but with separate ports?

Comment: Ports are hard to map to ticket ids, but it's a good point. I have to investigate that further.

Comment: Another option might be to make registering DNS part of your deployment process. Hopefully your deployment process is all scripted out, then you can just call an API to add the appropriate DNS entries for you, perhaps based on a shrunk down branch name. Then when you're done with that feature branch, you can have a cleanup process that removes the IIS site and removes the DNS entry.

Comment: Unfortunately registering dns entries involves manual work which is part of these policy reasons

Comment: It's manual *now*. But just like almost any other computer task, it's likely that it can be automated.

Comment: Yes, of cause. But right now it's not an option.

Comment: Have you tried an HTTP module installed on the sub apps to rewrite any paths in outgoing content?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about this?
Doesn't sound very reliable to find links in rendered output